# Youtube style slider with videos

Tags: jquery, css, video, youtube, slider

I'm going to build Youtube style inline slider for my videos. The exactly one, which you can find on main Youtube webpage.

I would like to ask you if you know some libaries which can help me, since I already searched some hours without sucess, but I don't like reinventing wheel ...

Basically, I need slider, which can display 5 (multiple) images (don't have to be videos) with text under them, and have an arrows on left and right side.

Every constructive answer will make me happy

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [**Swiper**](http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/#.WA-pHaNR6Rs) and its work awesome!
You can change the slide container for yours custom design (with iframe and content container).